# Odd stranger in town

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus

Here's a simple little puzzle.

With the help of the image below, can you figure out who I am?

---

[image]

Hint:

> Look carefully at the second "term". What could possibly be the word i'm looking for?

Hint(second term):

> what does the --- say?

Comment: This has been driving me mad. Any hints?!

Comment: V jnag gur pyrapurq svfg / zrqny vzntr gb or "Ivpgbel" orpnhfr V pna'g guvax bs nalguvat ryfr nccyvpnoyr jvgu 7 yrggref. Ohg gur 1 jbhyq cbvag gb gur svefg yrggre bs gung naq V pna'g svaq nalguvat gung ortvaf jvgu I gung jbhyq gura svg gur erfg bs gur pyhr.

Comment: Vs gur pyrapurq svfg / zrqny vzntr ercerfragrq "T" gura gur jubyr yrsg unaq vzntr pbhyq zrna "TUBFG". Gura gur evtug unaq vzntr jbhyq or "AB TUBFG". Ubjrire V'z abg fher jung gur 2 naq 16 zrna va gur hccre evtug pbearef.

Comment: Yrggre 2 vf O naq 16 vf C. Pbhyq guvf or n Tubfgohfgref gurzr naq O sbe Ovyy Zheenl  / C sbe Crgre Iraxznaa, gur punenpgre ur cynlrq? (Sne-srgpurq ohg pyhgpuvat ng fgenjf).

Comment: @Vicky Lbh'er svefg thrff vf evtug ertneqvat gur yrsg cneg bs gur vzntr. V fhfcrpgrq gur frpbaq cneg jvgu gur yrggref jbhyq or gur uneq cneg fb V'yy nqq n uvag sbe gung cneg.

Comment: BX, sbe gur frpbaq grez V unir gubhtug gung gur B vf ovttre guna gur bgure yrggref naq vf znqr hc bs gjb pbapragevp Bf. Fb ubfg (U Bf G); ubbg; B2 (nf va Bkltra) va U G... U pbhyq or Ulqebtra ohg G vfa'g na ryrzragny flzoby.
Qb gur 2 naq 16 ersre gb gur ahzore bs yrggref va gung cneg bs gur nafjre? Be fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu gur frpbaq yrggre naq fvkgrragu yrggre (O naq C) nf cre zl rneyvre pbzzrag?

Comment: Lrf, V qbag jnag gb fnl rknpgyl juvpu bar bs lbhe thrffrf vf pbeerpg (ertneqvat gur gjb Bf) ohg nqqvat gur svefg grez gb gung cneg jvyy znxr frafr (n jbeq). Nf sbe 2 naq 16, gurl'yy znxr frafr nsgre lbh svtherq bhg jung gur gjb grezf gbtrgure znxr hc (n jbeq)

Comment: WHAT IS THIS? Of the language

Comment: @AntsPiano You mean the language used in the comments above? => https://rot13.com/

Comment: Bx jbj, V pna’g oryvrir guvf, guvf qbrfa’g znxr frafr...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, here's my best guess.

The picture of the raised fist with the medal represents

> VICTORY (the 7 letter dashes underneath the picture).

The 1 in the corner of that represents

> the first letter of that, i.e. V

The letters on the right hand side of the + sign represent

> HOOT.

Based on the second hint we are actually looking for

> OWL

Adding these together, we get the left hand picture with 2 in the top right representing

> V + OWL = VOWEL, so there will be two vowels in the answer

Then the right hand picture with the whole lot crossed out and 16 in the top right represents

> 16 NOT-VOWELS, i.e. CONSONANTS.

So we are looking for a person whose name

> is made up of 2 vowels and 16 consonants.

Right now I can't think of anyone fitting this pattern, but I will come back and edit this later if an answer occurs to me.

OK, thanks to Hexomino who dragged me bodily across the finish line, we now know the first image represents

> not two vowels but the second vowel, E

and the second image represents

> not sixteen consonants but the 16th consonant, T

Putting these together we get

> E.T. (the Extra-Terrestrial) who was definitely an "odd stranger in town" per the puzzle title.

Comment: Well done on getting this. I had a thought that it may be that we are actually looking for rot13(gur frpbaq ibjry, R, naq gur fvkgrragu pbafbanag, G fb gur nafjre znl whfg or R.G.)

Comment: Oh, good catch. That would match with the title of the question as well (the odd stranger in town).

Comment: @hexomino Feel free to post that as an answer if you want - if you are right, it would not be fair for me to get the credit for that!

Comment: Okay, I've posted an answer but if you wanted to edit your answer with this in, I'm fine with that.

Comment: @Vicky Ah you were very close. But if yo do edit your answer and add what hexomino figured out (since he himself said it's ok), you'll get the tick.

Answer (score 4):

Vicky has done 99% of the work here so should get the credit for the answer but what I think we are really looking for is

> The 2nd vowel ("vowl") and the 16th consonant ("not vowl") which are, respectively **E** and **T**,
>  so the answer is probably **E.T.** (which fits with the title "Odd Stranger in Town")

Comment: Good job hexomino, But i dont think its fair if i didnt't give the tick to Vicky since she did alot of the work and you did the last part only. Hope it's ok.

Comment: @Prim3numbah Yep, that's very fair

Comment: Thank you both! I've edited my answer to include hexomino's part.